# Problems with filter and sorts in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, filter

I'm creating an app with the Pokemon API. I have the back ready, and on the front I work with redux and react.

What I do in the reducer I pass to a Filter.js file, which I import into Pokemons.js. In that last file, the only thing I do is map the array with all the pokemons.

The problem is that the filters and sorts are not working well. When I click on one of the Type options, it shows me the pokemons with that type, but then I can't choose another one. In the Created options, if I choose Data Base it shows me the ones created in the DB, but if I click on Api the page is reloaded and it shows me all the pokemons. And if I click on All, it does nothing.

I also couldn't get the sorts to work and if I touch the Clear Filter button everything breaks.

I think the problem is how the information passes from one side to the other, because I check the logic and I don't find any errors, but I'm no longer sure of anything.

This is the reducer:

```
import {
  GET_POKEMONS,
  GET_POKEMON_DETAIL,
  CREATE_POKEMON,
  DELETE_POKEMON,
  GET_TYPES,
  SORT_BY_ALPHABET,
  SORT_BY_ATTACK,
  FILTER_BY_CREATED,
  FILTER_BY_TYPE,
  SEARCH_POKEMON,
  CLEAN_FILTER,
} from "./actions";

const initialState = {
  pokemons: [],
  pokemonDetail: {},
  types: [],
  filterByType: null,
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_POKEMONS:
      return {
        ...state,
        pokemons: action.payload,
      };
    case GET_POKEMON_DETAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        pokemonDetail: action.payload,
      };

    case GET_TYPES:
      return {
        ...state,
        types: action.payload,
      };
    case CREATE_POKEMON:
      const name = action.payload.data.name;
      const speed = action.payload.data.speed;
      const hp = action.payload.data.hp;
      const height = action.payload.data.height;
      const weight = action.payload.data.weight;
      const attack = action.payload.data.attack;
      const defense = action.payload.data.defense;
      const createdInDB = action.payload.data.createdInDB;
      const types = action.payload.data.types;
      const img = action.payload.data.img;

      return {
        ...state,
        //pokemons: state.pokemons.concat({action.payload.data.name, action.payload.data.speed })
        pokemons: state.pokemons.concat({
          name,
          speed,
          hp,
          height,
          weight,
          attack,
          defense,
          createdInDB,
          types,
          img,
        }),
      };
    case DELETE_POKEMON:
      return {
        ...state,
        pokemons: state.pokemons.filter(
          (pokemon) => pokemon.id !== action.payload
        ),
      };

      //SORTS Y FILTERS
    case SORT_BY_ALPHABET:
      const sortAlpha =
        action.payload === "a-z"
          ? state.pokemons.sort((a, b) => {
              return a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase();
            })
          : state.pokemons.sort((a, b) => {
              return a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase();
            });
      return {
        ...state,
        pokemons: sortAlpha,
      };

    case SORT_BY_ATTACK:
      const sortAsc = state.pokemons.sort((a, b) => a.attack > b.attack);
      const sortDes = state.pokemons.sort((a, b) => a.attack < b.attack);
      const sortAttack = action.payload;
      if (sortAttack === "- to +")
        return {
          ...state,
          pokemons: sortAsc,
        };
      else if (sortAttack === "+ to -")
        return {
          ...state,
          pokemons: sortDes,
        };
      break;

    case FILTER_BY_TYPE:
      let type = action.payload;
      let pokemonFiltered = state.pokemons.filter((poke) => poke.types.includes(type))  
      console.log("filterByType", action.payload);
      if(pokemonFiltered.length > 0){
        return {
          ...state,
          pokemons: pokemonFiltered,
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          pokemons: state.pokemons
        }
      }

    case FILTER_BY_CREATED:
      let created = state.pokemons.filter((p) => typeof p.id === "string");
      let api = state.pokemons.filter((p) => typeof p.id === "number");
      if (action.payload === "Data Base") {
        console.log("action.payload is", action.payload);
        return {
          ...state,
          pokemons: created,
        };
      } else if (action.payload === "API") {
        console.log("action.payload is", action.payload);
        return {
          ...state,
          pokemons: api,
        };
      } else if (action.payload === "All") {
        console.log("action.payload is", action.payload);
        return {
          ...state,
          pokemons: state.pokemons,
        };
      }
      break;

    case SEARCH_POKEMON:
      return {
        ...state,
        pokemons: action.payload,
      };

    case CLEAN_FILTER: 
    return{
      ...state,
      pokemons: state.pokemons,
    }
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

This is actions.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const GET_POKEMONS = "GET_POKEMONS";
export const GET_POKEMON_DETAIL = "GET_POKEMON_DETAIL";
export const CREATE_POKEMON = "CREATE_POKEMON";
export const DELETE_POKEMON = "CREATE_POKEMON";
export const GET_TYPES = "GET_TYPES";

//Filtos y ordenamiento
export const FILTER_BY_TYPE = "FILTER_BY_TYPE";
export const FILTER_BY_CREATED = "FILTER_BY_CREATED";
export const SORT_BY_ALPHABET = "SORT_BY_ALPHABET";
export const SORT_BY_ATTACK = "SORT_BY_ATTACK";
export const CLEAN_FILTER = "CLEAR_FILTER"

export const SEARCH_POKEMON = "SEARCH_POKEMON";


export const getPokemons = () => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return fetch('http://localhost:3001/pokemons')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(pokemons => dispatch(
            {type: GET_POKEMONS, payload: pokemons}
        ))
    }
};

export const getPokemonDetail = (id) => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return fetch(`http://localhost:3001/pokemons/${id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => dispatch(
            {type: GET_POKEMON_DETAIL, payload: data[0]},
            console.log('data[0] in actions', data[0])
        ))
    }
};

export const createPokemon = (pokemon) => {
    // const options = {
    //     method: 'POST',
    //     headers: {
    //     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    //     },
    //     body: JSON.stringify(pokemon),
    //     };
    return async function(dispatch){
        const newPokemon = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/pokemons/`, pokemon)
       dispatch({type: CREATE_POKEMON, payload: newPokemon})
    }
    //return { type: CREATE_POKEMON, payload: pokemon}
};

export const deletePokemon = (id) => {
    return { type: DELETE_POKEMON, payload: id}
};

export const getTypes = () => {
    return function(dispatch){
        return fetch('http://localhost:3001/types')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(pokemons => {
            let types = [];
            pokemons.map((pokemon) => types.push(pokemon.types))
            dispatch ({type: GET_TYPES, payload: types})
        }
        )
    }
};

export const sortByAlphabet = (order) => {
    return ({type: SORT_BY_ALPHABET, payload: order});
}

export const sortByAttack = (order) => {
    return {type: SORT_BY_ATTACK, payload: order}
}

export const filterByType = (type) => {
    return {type: FILTER_BY_TYPE, payload: type}
}

export const filterByCreated = (value) => {
    return {type: FILTER_BY_CREATED, payload: value}
}

export const searchPokemon = (query) => (dispatch, getstate) => {
    const { pokemons } = getstate()
    const result = pokemons.searchPokemon.find((poke) => poke.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()));
    dispatch({ type: SEARCH_POKEMON, payload: result})
} 

export const cleanFilter = (payload) => {
    return {type: CLEAN_FILTER, payload}
}
```

This is Filters.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import s from "./Filters.module.css";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../../redux/actions";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Filters() {
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = React.useState("");
  const [selectValueB, setSelectValueB] = React.useState("");
  const [orden, setOrden] = useState("");
  const [ordenB, setOrdenB] = useState("");
  
  const history = useHistory(); 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const pokemons = useSelector((state) => state.pokemons);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!pokemons[0]) {
      dispatch(actions.getPokemons());
      dispatch(actions.getTypes());
    }
  }, [dispatch, pokemons]);

  function handleClick(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    const value = e.target.value;
    console.log('resetear filtros')
    dispatch(actions.cleanFilter(value))
    //history.push('/pokemons')
  };

  function handleFilterType(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    const value = e.target.value;
    setSelectValue(value); //para mostrarle a usuario lo que eligio
    dispatch(actions.filterByType(value)); //disapara la action del reducer
    history.push("/pokemons");
  }

  function handleFilterCreated(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = e.target.value;
    setSelectValueB(value);
    console.log('filtrar por creado')
    dispatch(actions.filterByCreated(value));
  }

  function handleSortByAlpha(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(actions.sortByAlphabet(e.target.value));
    setOrden(`Ordered from ${e.target.value}`)
    console.log('ordenado por alfabeto')
  }

  function handleSortByAttack(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(actions.sortByAttack(e.target.value));
    setOrdenB(`Ordered from ${e.target.value}`)
    console.log('ordenado por attack')
  }

  return (
    <div className={s.filterSection}>
      <div className={s.filters}>
        <h2 className={s.filterTitle}>Filters</h2>
        <div className={s.filterBy}>
          <h3 className={s.filterSubitle}>Filter by type</h3>

          <select
            className={s.select}
            value="default"
              onChange={(e) => handleFilterType(e)}
          >
            <option value="default" disabled hidden>
              Pokemon type
            </option>
            <option value="bug">bug</option>
            <option value="dark">dark</option>
            <option value="dragon">dragon</option>
            <option value="electric">electric</option>
            <option value="fairy">fairy</option>
            <option value="fighting">fighting</option>
            <option value="flying">flying</option>
            <option value="fire">fire</option>
            <option value="ghost">ghost</option>
            <option value="grass">grass</option>
            <option value="ground">ground</option>
            <option value="ice">ice</option>
            <option value="normal">normal</option>
            <option value="poison">poison</option>
            <option value="psychic">psychic</option>
            <option value="rock">rock</option>
            <option value="shadow">shadow</option>
            <option value="steel">steel</option>
            <option value="unknow">unknow</option>
            <option value="water">water</option>
          </select>
          {selectValue && <h3 className={s.showFilter}>{selectValue}</h3>}
      </div>
      
      <div className={s.filterBy}>
        <h3 className={s.filterSubitle}>Created in</h3>
        <select 
          className={s.select} 
          value="default"  
          onChange={e => handleFilterCreated(e)}
          >
          <option value="default" disabled hidden>
            Created in
          </option>
          <option value="All">All</option>
          <option value="API">API</option>
          <option value="Data Base">Data Base</option>
        </select>
        {selectValueB && <h3 className={s.showFilter}>{selectValueB}</h3>}
      </div>
    </div>
      
      <div className={s.filters}>
        <div className={s.filterBy}>
          <h3 className={s.filterSubitle}>Sort by Alphabet</h3>
          <select
            value="default"
            onChange={(e) => handleSortByAlpha(e)}
          >
            <option value="default" disabled hidden>
              Sort by Alphabet
            </option>
            <option value="a-z" onClick={(e) => handleSortByAlpha(e)}>From A to Z</option>
            <option value="z-a" onClick={(e) => handleSortByAlpha(e)}>From Z to A</option>
          </select>
          {orden && <h3 className={s.showFilter}>{orden}</h3>}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className={s.filters}>
        <div className={s.filterBy}>
          <h3 className={s.filterSubitle}>Sort by Attack</h3>
          <select
            value="default"
            onChange={(e) => handleSortByAttack(e)}
          >
            <option value="default" disabled hidden>
              Sort by Attack
            </option>
            <option value="- to +">From - to +</option>
            <option value="+ to -">From + to -</option>
          </select>
          {ordenB && <h3 className={s.showFilter}>{ordenB}</h3>}
        </div>
      </div>

      <button className={s.filterBtn} onClick={() => handleClick()}>Reset filters</button>
    </div>

  );
}
```

This is Pokemons.js

```
import React from 'react'
import s from './Pokemons.module.css'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import * as actions from '../../redux/actions'

//importo para poder mapear todas las cards
import PokeCard from '../PokeCard/PokeCard';
import Filters from '../Filters/Filters';

export default function Pokemons() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const pokemons = useSelector((state)=> state.pokemons);
  //const types = useSelector((state)=> state.types);
  const filterByType = useSelector((state)=> state.filterByType);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actions.getPokemons());
    dispatch(actions.getTypes());
  },[dispatch])

  console.log('filteredBytype', filterByType)
  return (
    <div className={s.pokemonsSection}>
      <Filters />
      <div className={s.allPokemons}>
        {//si hay un filterbytype mostra lo q incluya ese filtro. Si no existe mapea todo pokemons
          pokemons.map(poke =>{
            return <PokeCard 
            key={poke.id} 
            id={poke.id} 
            name={poke.name} 
            image={poke.img} 
            types={poke.types}/>
          }) 

        }
      </div>
    </div>  
  )
}
```

I tryed diferent ways to code the reducer and the filters, but I get the same results.
I wish you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see is that you are effectively mutating your "source of truth", i.e. the `state.pokemons` array. Each time `state.pokemons` is filtered the array size is less than or equal to its prior size. In other words, filtering is a reducing action, that array will never "remember" its prior elements once they are filtered, i.e. removed, from the array.

Filtered data is really ***derived*** state in that it is ***derived*** from some "source of truth" and a filtering condition. You don't want to mutate the original data, but you want to take *it* and the *filter condition* and *derive* a result to display.

I suggest storing the filtering conditions in the store and apply the filter/sorting when selecting the state. Adding/removing/editing should be done on the source data.

```
const initialState = {
  pokemons: [],
  pokemonDetail: {},
  types: [],
  filterByType: null,
  sortBy: {
    alpha: "a-z",
    attack: "- to +",
  },
  filters: {},
  search: "",
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_POKEMONS:
      return {
        ...state,
        pokemons: action.payload,
      };

    case GET_POKEMON_DETAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        pokemonDetail: action.payload,
      };

    case GET_TYPES:
      return {
        ...state,
        types: action.payload,
      };

    case CREATE_POKEMON:
      const newPokemon = {...action.payload.data};

      return {
        ...state,
        pokemons: state.pokemons.concat(newPokemon),
      };

    case DELETE_POKEMON:
      return {
        ...state,
        pokemons: state.pokemons.filter(
          (pokemon) => pokemon.id !== action.payload
        ),
      };

    //SORTS Y FILTERS
    case SORT_BY_ALPHABET:
      return {
        ...state,
        sortBy: {
          ...state.sortBy,
          alpha: action.payload
        },
      };

    case SORT_BY_ATTACK:
      return {
        ...state,
        sortBy: {
          ...state.sortBy,
          attack: action.payload
        },
      };

    case FILTER_BY_TYPE:
      return {
        ...state,
        filterBy: {
          ...state.filterBy,
          type: action.payload,
        },
      };

    case FILTER_BY_CREATED:
      return {
        ...state,
        filterBy: {
          ...state.filterBy,
          created: action.payload,
        },
      };

    case SEARCH_POKEMON:
      return {
        ...state,
        search: action.payload,
      };

    case CLEAN_FILTER: 
      return {
        ...state,
        sortBy: initialState.sortBy,
        filterBy: initialState.filterBy,
        search: initialState.search,
      }

    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};
```

Update the `searchPokemon` action creator to just store the search query term lowercased.

```
export const searchPokemon = (query) => ({
  type: SEARCH_POKEMON,
  payload: query.toLowerCase()
});
```

Create a pokemon state selector function that does the work of filtering/sorting the `state.pokemons` array. Keep in mind that the `.sort` function callback should return a number (*`-1|0|1`*) instead of a boolean to indicate the sorted order between two elements. The `.filter` function callback returns a boolean if the current element should be included in the result array.

```
const pokemonSelector = state => {
  return state.pokemons
    .filter(pokemon => {
      // NOTE: All strings include ""
      return pokemon.name.toLowerCase().includes(state.search);
    })
    .filter(pokemon => {
      return state.filterBy.type
        ? pokemon.types.includes(state.filterBy.type)
        : true
    })
    .filter(pokemon => {
      switch(state.filterBy.created) {
        case "Data Base":
          return typeof pokemon.id === "string";
        case "API":
          return typeof pokemon.id === "number";
        default:
          return true;
      }
    })
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return state.sortBy.alpha === "a-z"
        ? a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase())
        : b.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(a.name.toLowerCase());
    })
    .sort((a, b) => {
      switch(state.sortBy.attack) {
        case "- to +":
          return a.attack - b.attack;
        case "+ to -":
          return b.attack - a.attack;
        default:
          return 0;
      }
    });
};
```

Update the `Pokemons` component to import this new `pokemonSelector` selector function and pass this to the `useSelector` hook to compute the ***derived*** selected state.

```
...
import { pokemonSelector } from '../path/to/selectors';

export default function Pokemons() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const pokemons = useSelector(pokemonSelector); // gets filtered/sorted pokemons

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actions.getPokemons());
    dispatch(actions.getTypes());
  },[dispatch])

  return (
    <div className={s.pokemonsSection}>
      <Filters />
      <div className={s.allPokemons}>
        {pokemons.map(poke => (
          <PokeCard 
            key={poke.id} 
            id={poke.id} 
            name={poke.name} 
            image={poke.img} 
            types={poke.types}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>  
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Drew. I will try to do all these change.

Comment: can you explain me what is pokemonSelector? Is it a new file that I should include in the reducer folder? Is is a new reducer? If it is a reducer, I have to use combineReducer, rigth? Thanks for your help, this really far from my knowledge.

Comment: @NicoBonder Ah, sure. `pokemonSelector` is a state selector function, similar to your OG `state => state.pokemons` selector function in `useSelector` hook but with more logic to compute the derived "state" value. It doesn't *need* to be declared in a separate file, but chances are you'd want to anyway for code reuse (*i.e. another component needs to select the same "state"*). It's not a reducer, and `combineReducers` is only used when building up a more complex Redux state tree. Does this help clear up things for you?

Comment: @NicoBonder For more information on selectors in general see the [RTK](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector) and the [Reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) docs.